# How to split string using text to columns in excel with different delimiters?

Tags: excel

```
"CAN:INSIDE:LED,Commercial-Business,:Engineering:&:Consumer:Services:"
```

I want the above string to be split as US,Inside LED, Commercial,Business Engineering & Consumer Services Education in different columns using data tab of excel. Some answers will really help me.

Comment: First split using :  then where you have columns that need to be spilt using ,  insert Columns to the right of them and spilt again or use formula to split,.  Proper delimited files would never use two delimiters as you may have valid text that contains the second delimiter which couldn't be escaped accurately.

Comment: The Solution i would suggest is, Replace your delimiters with the supported type by using Replace All option like ':' to ";",'-" to ':' and then directly use Excels Text to Column option.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys !!